# Will "mousedown" and "mousemove" change the cursor icon and how to prevent it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

I have a little sketch application. We can press down the mouse and paint something.

When `mousedown` and `mouseenter` event happens to a cell, it change the color.  But this combination is somehow similar to `drag`. Sometime this "little earth" icon appears, and then `mouseup` event will be swollen. Anyone knows where does this "little earth icon" come from?
[image]

I've already set the `cell.draggable = false`. No `drag` event is fired.

Here's my code to reproduce the bug. It's very rare, maybe 1/20 to 1/50 of chance. Click first the `create canvas` button than you can paint.

```js
/* create grids in canvas */
const initCanvas = function() {
    const canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
    /* clear old canvas if any */
    canvas.innerHTML = '';
    /* create new canvas */
    let row = parseInt(document.querySelector('textarea.canvasRow').value);
    let column = parseInt(document.querySelector('textarea.canvasColumn').value);
    if (!row || !column) return;
    canvas.style['grid-template-columns'] = `repeat(${column}, 1fr)`;
    canvas.style['grid-template-rows'] = `repeat(${row}, 1fr)`;
    for (let i = 0; i < (row * column); i++) {
        let cell = document.createElement('div');
        cell.classList.add('cell');
        cell.addEventListener('mousedown', draw, false);
        cell.addEventListener('mouseenter', draw, false);
        canvas.appendChild(cell);
    }
}

/* mousedown event handler on canvas */
const toDraw = function(e) {
    isDrawing = true;
}

/* mousemove event handler on each cell */
const draw = function(e) {
    if (isDrawing) {
        this.style['background-color'] = color;
    }
}

/* mouseup event handler on whole document */
const stopDrawing = function(e) {
    isDrawing = false;
    e.stopPropagation();
}

/* variables */
let color = 'black';
let isDrawing = false;
/* canvas init */
const initCanvasBtn = document.querySelector('.initCanvas');
initCanvasBtn.addEventListener('click', initCanvas);
/* draw */
const canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', toDraw, true); // capture must be true. canvas must turn on "isDrawing" before cell capture the mousedown event.
document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrawing, true); // document element handle this. no need to notify children.
```

```css
textarea.canvasRow,
textarea.canvasColumn {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 1rem;
}

.initCanvas {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.canvas {
  height: 50vw;
  width: 50vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
}

.cell {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="canvasRow">16</textarea>
<textarea class="canvasColumn">16</textarea>
<div class="initCanvas">Create canvas</div>
<div class="canvas"></div>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? My cursor turns into "no-drop" occasionally (Chromium MSEdge).

Comment: i use google  chrome

Comment: On what other occasions do the earth icon appear?

Comment: No, just when I'm drawing the picture. I think the "little earth" is the `no-drop` icon for my browser.

Comment: Try setting `draggable="off"` and see what happens.

Comment: I don't see the globe icon on my browser (chrome),  have you tried preventDefault() on mouse down ?

Comment: already set it to `draggable="false"`, otherwise the cell would be dragged out of the canvas everytime.

Comment: Seems `event.preventDefault()` works. The globe icon never shows up again.

Comment: So what does `preventDefault()` do for us?

Comment: I think you are correct. You can leave a formal answer so I can accept it.