# Why drag and dragstart event are still triggered when draggable attribute is set to false?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this sketch application, which allows user to draw some pictures by pressing and moving the mouse.

```js
/* create grids in canvas */
const initCanvas = function() {
    const canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
    /* clear old canvas if any */
    canvas.innerHTML = '';
    /* create new canvas */
    let row = parseInt(document.querySelector('textarea.canvasRow').value);
    let column = parseInt(document.querySelector('textarea.canvasColumn').value);
    if (!row || !column) return;
    canvas.style['grid-template-columns'] = `repeat(${column}, 1fr)`;
    canvas.style['grid-template-rows'] = `repeat(${row}, 1fr)`;
    for (let i = 0; i < (row * column); i++) {
        let cell = document.createElement('div');
        cell.classList.add('cell');
        cell.draggable = false; // prevent cell from being dragged
        cell.addEventListener('mousedown', draw, false);
        cell.addEventListener('mouseenter', draw, false); // mouseenter is better than mouseover
        canvas.appendChild(cell);
    }
}

/* mousedown event handler on canvas */
const toDraw = function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault(); // !IMPORTANT: inhibit some browser's default drag & drop behaviors
    isDrawing = true;
}

/* mouseenter event handler on each cell */
const draw = function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault(); // !IMPORTANT: inhibit some browser's default drag & drop behaviors
    if (isDrawing) {
        this.style['background-color'] = color;
    }
}

/* mouseup event handler on whole document */
const stopDrawing = function(e) {
    isDrawing = false;
    e.stopPropagation();
}

/* variables */
let color = 'black';
let isDrawing = false;
/* canvas init */
const initCanvasBtn = document.querySelector('.initCanvas');
initCanvasBtn.addEventListener('click', initCanvas);
/* draw */
const canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
canvas.draggable = false; // prevent canvas from being dragged
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', toDraw, true); // capture must be true. canvas must turn on "isDrawing" before cell capture the mousedown event.
document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrawing, true); // document element handle this. no need to notify children.
```

```css
textarea.canvasRow,
textarea.canvasColumn {
    width: 4rem;
    height: 1rem;
}

.initCanvas {
    width: 4rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.canvas {
    height: 50vw;
    width: 50vw;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: grid;
}

.cell {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="canvasRow">16</textarea>
<textarea class="canvasColumn">16</textarea>
<div class="initCanvas">Create canvas</div>
<div class="canvas"></div>
```

According to [MDN Web Docs: draggable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable), to prevent element from being dragged, I set the `draggable` attribute of both `canvas` and `cell` to `false`.

```js
cell.draggable = false;
canvas.draggable = false;
```

But when I test it, in 1/20 or 1/30 of cases, a `no-drop` cursor icon appears, and my `mouseup` event will be swollen. That means a `drag operation` occurred, which is not expected.

[image]

According to [MDN Web Docs: HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) I bind a listener on `dragstart` and `drag` event. Then debugger's `Event Listener Breakpoint` showed that both `drag` and `dragstart` events were fired when bug occured.
[image]

In another previous question: [Will "mousedown" and "mousemove" change the cursor icon and how to prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71001320/will-mousedown-and-mousemove-change-the-cursor-icon-and-how-to-prevent-it), @skmail suggested me to add `preventDefault()` on `mousedown` event.

It works! `drag` and `dragstart` event disappeared. But I still want to know: **why `drag` and `dragstart` event can still be triggered when elements are configured as `draggable=false`?** I mean there's almost nothing but hundreds of empty `div`. And they are all undraggable`... I'm really confused.

It would be very nice if you can further explain **why `preventDefault()` can solve this problem?** For now, the only thing I'm sure is that this unexpected `drag operation` is trigger by browser's default setting. Anyone have some hint?

Comment: There are nothing but hundreds of div in my canvas. No texts, nor links. I don’t see any chance that a cursor event can be triggered by default?

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you mean. But I’m pretty sure that a `drag operation` occurred which change the cursor appearance to that "little earth", and that is not what I expected.

Comment: If you change `cell.draggable=true` you will see the entire cell is pulled off. I set them to `false`, so no `drag` event happened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241761/discussion-between-shen-and-savagegoat).

Comment: Oh my bad. That because the Canvas is not draggable yet the divs that you generate are. Your solution would be something like `pointer-events: painted;` or `user-drag: none;` on the canvas AND the divs too to avoid drag

Comment: ok, I'll check that.

Comment: Note: that's not a no-drop cursor in your image. It's a [globe icon](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Symbols%20Outlined%3Aglobe%3AFILL%400%3Bwght%40400%3BGRAD%400%3Bopsz%4024).

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is unfortunately not standardized. Here's what's happening:

When you paint across the canvas the first time, the (empty) text nodes inside the div are being selected. Browsers handle selections separately, so they're not governed by the draggable attribute. If you drag from inside the selection, the drag events will trigger. `preventDefault()` on `mousedown` simply prevents that selection from happening.

**The simpler solution in your case is to add `user-select: none;` to .canvas.** (don't forget to add `webkit-` for Safari browsers).

A related, but more complicated case is when you have a text input on top of a draggable div. In this case, it's important to set your logic correctly so selection drags aren't misinterpreted as the div being dragged.